# loading page shifts

Tags: html

(When loading) For some reason the content of my page shifts down really far while the background is stationary and then jumps back up to the appropriate placement. Anyone know why or how to fix this issue? I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: What does your page contain? Are you using any javascript? Is it plain HTML, or are you using PHP, ASP.NET or similar?

Comment: We'd need to see some css/html to help you sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your background isn't really a background, but rather a layer with an image in it that you've stacked behind your content.

I generally find this to be a pain because if for some reason the z-index of the items get's confused (and it sounds like this is what's happening here), weird things will happen when the page loads.

I personally recommend you set the background image on the same block that all your content goes on. Consider the following

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="header"> </div>
    <div class="navigation"> <!-- Menu goes here --> </div>

    <div class="main"> <!-- Main content goes here --> </div>
</div>

#content { background: transparent url("Images/mybackground.png"); }
```

This will set the background on the page element that also houses your content. Assuming I've identified the problem corrently, this should solve your problem.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the post, maybe this will help pin point the issue:

http://ag625.com/ag625.com/agtest/talk.html

Here is a link to our test page, I set my background up as body {
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 background-image: url(NIWBGtalkVfinal.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left top;
}

is that a bad idea? Maybe I should be setting it up differently, or is there something else it may be?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the way you set the background, but I've never used background-attachment...
None of the websites I'm working on at the moment have background images, but I have to say, I've never had the background image jump before.
Anyway, here's some shorthand that'll shorten it for you: `body { background: #ffffff url("NIWBGtalkVfinal.jpg") no-repeat left top; }`
I've never used some of the properties you're working with so just check that it works before assuming I'm right.

Comment: For the record, I don't see anything doing something weird on the page you linked when I load it. It looks great.